# TCP File transfer with htonl & htons

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I am doing a file transfer program in c++ right now.  It works but the only problem is I am using getline instead of read().  So the program seems to only do text files. I read in the file and store in in a char*[]. So I was wondering when I change it to read() in binary and want to send it through the sockets, do I need to do a conversion(htons,htonl, etc) on the char*[] before I pass it over?  I read somewhere that you don't need to do that if it's a char*.  Am I mistaken in how I am storing the information from the file?

to sum up:
 How do I store information read in from a binary opened file?
 If it is stored in a char*[], do I need to use htons... on it, and how?
 how many bytes would I send over the sockets at a time?

Thanks very much for your any help everyone!

Comment: htons/htonl are needed only when you're sending ints/longs, for char - it does not make sense, as char is 1 byte

Comment: To be precise htons/ntohs are for 16bit integers, whereas htonl/ntohl are for 32 bits integers. Reference (Linux): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htons.3.html

Comment: endian issues don't affect single byte streams such as `char[]` - they only matter for multibyte types like `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `struct`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to convert the file data, send/read it as-is.

What you should do, however, is assign the file size to a variable, convert it with `htonl()`, and send it before then sending the file data.  Then the receiver can read the file size, convert it with `ntohl()`, and know how many bytes to read for the file data so it knows when to stop reading and whether the full file was received or not.

Comment: ok so is storing the file in a char*[] the right way to go about it then for transferring files over tcp?

Comment: No, `char*[]` is an array of `char*` pointers, which is not what you want. Use `char[]` instead, or even `unsigned char[]` (or `uint8[]` or `uint8_t[]`, if your compiler supports that).

Comment: As a side note: converting the file size using htonl/ntohl implies transfering the file size as 32 bit value, which limits the file size to a maximum of 4GB (unsigned 32bit).

Comment: There are some third-party 64-bit implementations of `htonl()` floating around. Or you can simply split a 64bit number into 32bit halves and use `htonl()` on each half.